# result in form search using pdo php

Tags: php, pdo

this code gives no result even if the word exists in database

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query'];
$min_length = 3;

if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $query = $DB_con->quote($query);

    $raw_results = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM e3lanat
WHERE (`e_title` LIKE '%" . $query . "%') OR (`e_content` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')");

    if ($raw_results->rowCount() > 0) {

        while ($results = $raw_results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

            echo "<p><h3>" . $results->e_title . "</h3>" . $results->e_content . "</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results 2";
}
?>

<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="بحث عن إعلانات " style='width:300px;'>
    <button type="submit" value="Search"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$raw_results = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM e3lanat
    WHERE (`e_title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`e_content` LIKE '%".$query."%')");

if($raw_results->rowCount() > 0){
```

You only `prepare()` the query, but not `execute()`-ing it.

Comment: Mr LeleDumbo htlp please

Comment: google first what parameters does execute expect, don't wildly add the method call without knowing how to call the method.